# Could an interference pattern help us predict the location of an electron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, superposition

Interference pattern occurs during the double slit experiment but is is possible to predict an electron's position based on that pattern

Answer (score 1):

The interference pattern gives you an indication of the probability of finding an electron at a particular point on the screen. In that sense, it allow *some* predictive power: not every location is equally likely. It's like being in a casino, and being told the next number on the roulette wheel will be even. That doesn't mean you can predict the number - but your chances of guessing it just got doubled.

Comment: How about use multiple interference patterns and compare results to narrow down selection?

Comment: An infinitely wide slot gives you an infinitely narrow interference pattern... in other words if you shoot an electron straight you have the best chance of knowing where it is.